# Where can I find more information on a bug that causes rendering issues with ubuntu-gnome textareas in 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I'm encountering a bug in Ubuntu Gnome. Many text-areas show their background in the place of the text-area; this makes typing there hard, since you cannot see what is typed.

Example is the calculator:

[image: calculator screenshot showing the issue]

The grey-black is a piece of my wallpaper.

This also happens with gnome-calendar, -contacts etc. Basically any gnome app that has a text-area.

Note that the area is not transparent, when the window is moved, the image remains in place. It clearly is some rendering or artifact at the moment of rendering the area. It always shows what was behind it, at the moment the window appears. In the screenshot that was the wallpaper. But it might be what is shown in another window, if the textarea is in a dialog above that window.

I have searched launchpad, but am clueless what keywords to look for.

1. Is this is a known bug? Where can I find this?
2. What should I look for? What keywords, components or tags should I use in order to find a bug-report.
3. When submitting a bug-report, what component causes this? Is it a theme? A setting? A video-card-issue? Something else?

I have upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. (And previously from 14.04 and -not sure- even from 12:04). So It might very well be an upgrade-issue, or some ancient config-option that is incompatible; though I hardly change settings other than the one Ubuntu uses (e.g. I don't ever use the -tweak tools).

Comment: `gnome-calculator` and some other apps pre-installed in 18.04 are [snap applications](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro) (check by running `snap list`). Try removing the snap one (`snap remove gnome-calculator`) and install the traditional apt one (`sudo apt install gnome-calculator`) and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, then most probably the issue is with snaps.

Comment: I've tried that already. Gnome-calculator is not installed as snap on my system, but as apt and the problem *persists*. so: the problem occurs in both snap installations and in apt installations.

Thanks for giving that solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that a fix for another, unrelated issue, causes this.  That fix, was to set the input method from `IBus` to `XIM`. Setting it to `XIM` causes the weird transparancy glitch.

Reverting the input-method back to `IBus` fixes all the weird transparancy-issues. Not just in gnome-calculator, but in e.g. gedit too.

Here's the [page with fix for unrelated, MetaMask issue](https://consensys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007617432), that I followed and which is what caused this bug to appear. Here's the bug-report with [a comment by letatcest explaining the transparancy -issue that this fix causes](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3313#issuecomment-418677844).